# For loop on dates in R

Tags: r, date, loops, for-loop

R-users,
I have this dataframe:

```
head(M2006)
        X.ID_punto   MM.GG.AA  Rad_SWD 
2945377          1 0001-01-06  19.918  
2945378          2 0001-01-06  19.911   
2945379          1 0001-02-06  19.903  
2945380          2 0001-02-06  19.893   
2945381          1 0001-03-06  19.875 
2945382          2 0001-03-06  19.858
```

What I need to do is to obtain different subsets for every dates (MM.GG.AA):

```
subset(M2006, M2006$MM.GG.AA=="0001-10-06" )
```

or, in other words, different subsets for every sites (X.ID_punto):

```
subset(M2006, M2006$X.ID_punto==1)
```

Is it possible to loop this on sites (X.ID_punto) or dates (MM.GG.AA)?
I have tried in this way:

```
 output<- data.frame(ID=rep(1:365))
 for  (p in as.factor(M2006[,1]))  { 
             sub<-  subset(M2006, M2006$X.ID_punto==p )
             output[,p] <- sub$Rad_SWD
      }
```

the code run, but without looping on every ID.
If I can't loop, I have to write down subset(M2006, M2006$X.ID_punto==xxx) for a thousand times...
Thank you in advance!
Fra

Comment: The answer depends on what you're trying to do with your subsets, I guess. What is the 6th column of your data frame ? What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: I'm sorry Juba, in the original dataset I have different column. And the 6th contain the data that I want to subset for sites. This column is Rad_SWD, the 3rd reported in my example.

Comment: by the way, maybe I've found a possible solution, I'd like to have your opinion on this

Comment: @SimonO101, sorry I didn't know that. Done ;-)

Comment: @FraNut no problem - that's what I thought, which is why I gave you the pointers! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from your description of input and desired output you an acheive this pretty simply using the `reshape` package and the `cast` function:

```
require(reshape)
cast( M2006 , MM.GG.AA ~ X.ID_punto , value = .(Rad_SWD) )
#   MM.GG.AA      1      2
#1 0001-01-06 19.918 19.911
#2 0001-02-06 19.903 19.893
#3 0001-03-06 19.875 19.858
```

It will certainly be quicker than using loops ( it isn't going to be the absolute quickest solution but I imagine < 1-2 seconds).

Comment: Awesome! It looks like pivot in excel, isn't it?

Comment: @FraNut Yes, it is analogous to that (but I would imagine a lot more powerful - although I don't know the full capabilities of pivot tables)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution by myself.
I won't cancel my question, maybe someone will find it useful.

```
   #first of all, since I have 1008 sites (X.ID_punto)
    #I created a list of my sites       
    list<- rep(1:1008)

    #then, create a dataframe where I'll store my subsets. 
    #Every subset will be a column of 365 observations
    output<- data.frame(site1=rep(1:365))

    #loop the subset function on list of 1008 sites
    for  (p in 1:length(list))  { 
      print(p)  #just to see if loop run
      sub<-  subset(M2006, M2006$X.ID_punto==p )
      output[,p] <- sub$Rad_SWD #add the subset, as a column, to output dataframe 
    }
    write.csv(uscita, "output.csv")#save the resulted data frame
```